# Game won't auto rotate on iOS 8/iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a landscape-only game that auto rotates fine on the following:

- Any iPad on iOS 6+
- iPhone 4S on iOS 7

But not on:

- iPod 5 on iOS 8
- iPhone 5S on iOS 8
- iPhone 6/6+ on iOS 8

Those are the configurations I have access to. I am using storyboards with a single UIView filling the screen, no auto layout or anything. The following code is in my view controller:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

This is called as expected on all devices when rotated. On iPads, I can see that willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: and then didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: are invoked. These methods never trigger on my iOS 8 phones. My plist includes the following:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

I am out of ideas here - why won't my app rotate on the iOS 8 phones?

[UPDATE] I've narrowed it down to something else: the code I use to select storyboards based on device, in my app delegate:

```
if (width == 480)
{
    // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone

    UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
    UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
    self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

    // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

if (width == 568)
{   // iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th generation: 4 inch screen
    // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone4
    UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone_4in" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Your first `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key lists `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` twice. Is that a typo on the website, or is that in your file?

Comment: Copy paste typo there, I've corrected it. If only the actual code had made it that simple for me....